# How to list all registered JAX-RS Entity Providers in Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

Let's suppose i have simple jersey app with embedded jetty [Demo project on github](https://github.com/varren/jersey2-gradle-embedded-jetty-demo-repo) and essential code below.

Back in the days with jersey1 i had log messages:

```
мая 07, 2016 5:05:50 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  ru.varren
мая 07, 2016 5:05:50 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class ru.varren.MyResource
мая 07, 2016 5:05:50 AM com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Provider classes found:
  class ru.varren.JsonProvider
мая 07, 2016 5:05:50 AM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.1 03/11/2016 02:08 PM'
```

But now i am trying to work with jersey2 and thiere is no more log info. So, my question is **how to list all registered JAX-RS Entity Providers**. I don't care much where to list them. In `main` function or in some  `@GET` `MyResource` method. Probably i should change something in my setup or put logger boolean, but cant find it.

This is purely for testing purpose. Simple print of all providers classes will be enough for me. Cooler option is to print provider and accosiated `@Produces` and `@Consumes` MediaType.

**MyResource.java**

```
@Path("test")
public class MyResource {

    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response  getPersons() {
        return Response.ok("[some data here]").build();
    }

}
```

**MyApplication.java**

```
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(9998).build();
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(MyResource.class);
        config.packages("ru.varren");
        Server server = JettyHttpContainerFactory.createServer(baseUri, config, true);
        server.join();
    }

}
```

And **gradle.build**

```
dependencies {  
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.22.2'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:2.22.2'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.22.2'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-jetty-http:2.22.2'

    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:9.1.0.M0'
    compile 'org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:9.1.0.M0'
}
```

Comment: I might try using an [`ApplicationEventListener`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.22.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/monitoring/ApplicationEvent.html), and on "application initiaized" use the methods on the [`ApplicationEvent`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.22.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/monitoring/ApplicationEvent.html) to get the resources and providers

Comment: @peeskillet yep, exectly what i was looking for.  `applicationEvent.getProviders()` in `onEvent` method in custom `ApplicationEventListener` class gives me all the info i need. https://i.gyazo.com/7050dccb82d4c2445709b2079817ce00.png And here is also cool docs  https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/monitoring_tracing.html . Can you please post your comment as answer? I will mark it as an Accepted answer

Comment: @peeskillet Is there any vendor-neutral API for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use an [`ApplicationEventListener`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/monitoring_tracing.html#d0e15631), and on `INITIALIZATION_FINISHED`, you can get a set of resources and providers from the [`ApplicationEvent`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.22.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/monitoring/ApplicationEvent.html). For example

```
@Provider
public class ProviderLoggingListener implements ApplicationEventListener {
 
    @Override
    public void onEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        switch (event.getType()) {
            case INITIALIZATION_FINISHED: {
                Set<Class<?>> providers = event.getProviders();
                ResourceConfig immutableConfig = event.getResourceConfig();
                ResourceModel resourcesModel = event.getResourceModel();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
 
    @Override
    public RequestEventListener onRequest(RequestEvent requestEvent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**See Also:**

- [Listing all deployed rest endpoints (spring-boot, jersey)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32525699/2587435), which shows an example of traversing the `ResourceModel`