# List all registered JAX-RS 2 providers in implementation-independent way

Tags: java, jax-rs

I just wondering is it possible to list all registered JAX-RS 2.0 providers in implementation-independent way? I found on SO that [Jersey 2 has such capability](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37084771/2881869) by using internal classes for this, e.g. [ApplicationEventListener](https://jersey.github.io/apidocs/latest/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/monitoring/ApplicationEventListener.html). But I'm searching vendor-agnostic solution to do such thing. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: cxf.jaxrs.classes-scan-packages=demo.path