# Jersey, List of Implemeted webservices

Tags: java, jersey

Just wanted to know, if there is a way, I can find out the list of implemented rest services which are using Jersey.

Thanks

Comment: This isn't clear.  What is your definition of "implemented rest service" in this context?  Do you mean a list of Jersey resource class/methods?

Comment: Sorry! ** I already have tons of working rest services which do certain thing **, what I want to get is the list of all those working/implemented services.

Comment: Dropwizard uses Jersey and does a fairly nice job of displaying configured endpoints, is that what you need? Take a look at https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-jersey/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/jersey/DropwizardResourceConfig.java#L127

Comment: @MichaelBarnwell, I guess this should do the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Also can use the following link, it has the nice implementation of dropwizard Michael was talking about

[Listing all deployed rest endpoints (spring-boot, jersey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32525699/listing-all-deployed-rest-endpoints-spring-boot-jersey)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can get the same functionality by using using an Aspect.