# Is there a way to get a list of all jersey urls a user, based on their role and @RolesAllowed, has access to?

Tags: java, rest, jersey-2.0

I am hoping to offer a rest api call to clients(via plain jersey, not spring) to return a list of all endpoints allowed for the specific user based on the JWT they send in the header.  I have found on stackoverflow(thanks contributors!) example code to get all endpoints, regardless of role, but not the subset based on role.  I have found how to get the annotations per method as well, but would like to avoid re-inventing the wheel of "if @PermitAll and not @DenyAll, or role in RolesAllowed, etc...".

Any chance Jersey 2.0 has a a method I can call that will resolve to true/false given SecurityContext and url endpoint or method?

boolean allowed = isMethodAllowed(SecurityContext ctx, String url);

Or

boolean allowed = isMethodAllowed(SecurityContext ctx, Class method);

Comment: You seem to understand what you will need to do to implement this yourself. There is nothing like this built in, so yes, you will have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this post: [Listing all deployed rest endpoints (spring-boot, jersey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32525699/listing-all-deployed-rest-endpoints-spring-boot-jersey)

Specifically Johanne Jander's post(thank you!), I've come up with the below code which seems to work in my case, a simple jersey use case.  Providing it here in case it's useful to others.

```
@Path("/v1/userinterface")
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
public class MyUI extends MyRestApi {

    private final static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyUI.class);

    @Context
    private Configuration configuration;

    @Context
    private SecurityContext security;

    @Path("/allowedendpoints")
    @GET
    @Operation(summary = "List API access points allowed for the currently authenticated user", tags = {
        "ui" }, description = "Returns a list of urls", responses = {})
    public Response showAll(@Context UriInfo ui) {

    log.debug("Get list of all allowed endpoints for user: " + security.getUserPrincipal().getName());

    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

    for (Class<?> c : configuration.getClasses()) {
        // Since all of my endpoint classes extend MyRestApi,
        // only scan them, not all classes
        if (MyRestApi.class.isAssignableFrom(c)) {
        scanClass(c, map);
        }
    }

    return Response.ok().entity(map).build();
    }

    public void scanClass(Class<?> baseClass, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map) {
    Builder builder = Resource.builder(baseClass);
    if (null != builder) {
        Resource resource = builder.build();
        String uriPrefix = "";
        process(uriPrefix, resource, map);
    }
    }

    private void process(String uriPrefix, Resource resource, HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map) {

    // recursive method

    String pathPrefix = uriPrefix;
    List<Resource> resources = new ArrayList<>();
    resources.addAll(resource.getChildResources());

    if (resource.getPath() != null) {
        pathPrefix = (pathPrefix + "/" + resource.getPath()).replaceAll("//", "/");
    }

    for (ResourceMethod method : resource.getAllMethods()) {
        if (method.getType().equals(ResourceMethod.JaxrsType.SUB_RESOURCE_LOCATOR)) {
        resources.add(Resource
            .from(resource.getResourceLocator().getInvocable().getDefinitionMethod().getReturnType()));
        } else {
        if (isPathAllowed(security, method.getInvocable().getDefinitionMethod())) {
            if (map.containsKey(pathPrefix))
            map.get(pathPrefix).add(method.getHttpMethod());
            else
            map.put(pathPrefix, new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(method.getHttpMethod())));
        }
        }
    }

    for (Resource childResource : resources) {
        process(pathPrefix, childResource, map);
    }
    }

    public boolean isPathAllowed(SecurityContext ctx, Method method) {

    // @DenyAll on the method takes precedence over @RolesAllowed and @PermitAll
    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(DenyAll.class)) {
        return (false);
    }

    // @RolesAllowed on the method takes precedence over @PermitAll
    RolesAllowed rolesAllowed = method.getAnnotation(RolesAllowed.class);
    if (rolesAllowed != null) {
        return (hasRole(ctx, rolesAllowed.value()));
    }

    // @PermitAll on the method takes precedence over @RolesAllowed on the class
    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(PermitAll.class)) {
        return (true);
    }

    // @DenyAll can't be attached to classes

    // @RolesAllowed on the class takes precedence over @PermitAll on the class
    rolesAllowed = method.getDeclaringClass().getAnnotation(RolesAllowed.class);
    if (rolesAllowed != null) {
        return (hasRole(ctx, rolesAllowed.value()));
    }

    // @PermitAll on the class
    if (method.getDeclaringClass().isAnnotationPresent(PermitAll.class)) {
        return (true);
    }

    return (false); // default
    }

    private boolean hasRole(SecurityContext ctx, String[] rolesAllowed) {

    for (final String role : rolesAllowed) {
        if (ctx.isUserInRole(role)) {
        return (true);
        }
    }

    return (false);
    }
```

Which returns endpoints the currently authenticated user has access to based on SecurityContext markup with the @DenyAll, @PermitAll and @RolesAllowed annotations.

Full disclosure, my app is simple with just basic class and method annotations at the endpoints. ymmv.

Sample output:

```
{
   "/v1/resources" : [
      "POST",
      "GET"
   ],
   "/v1/resources/{id}" : [
      "DELETE",
      "GET"
   ]
}
```